# Hadoop Jersey conflicts with Wildfly resteasy

Tags: jakarta-ee, hadoop, jersey, resteasy, wildfly

On a J2EE project we use Wildfly to deploy the project. We run hadoop on an external server. We want to connect this server and read HDFS data. But the problem is, any hadoop library we use(hadoop-common, hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-client) needs Jersey but wildfly use Resteasy. Because of this confliction, Wildfly does not deploy successfully.

My question is,

Is there any hadoop library, which does not depend Jersey, we can use for this operation, or,

Do we need to replace Resteasy on Wildfly with Jersey. If this is the solution, how can we do that. We couldn't find a source for this solution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you mean [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) rather than Jetty?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, I will edit the question now.

Comment: [hadoop-client 2.7.1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.7.1/hadoop-client-2.7.1.pom) appears to exclude the Jersey dependencies. Are you sure about where the dependencies are from?

Comment: We use hadoop 2.6.0 version and  yes I am sure.

Comment: Have you tried excluding the Jersey deps? If the hadoop-client is accessing the Jersey implementation via the javax.ws.rs API then it may just work.

Comment: Also, I have tried 2.7.1 client, but problem still occurs

Comment: Yes , I did but a lot of component depends on jersey and in this case, those are not running.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue with Hadoop 2.7.1 on WildFly 8.2.

Comment: No, I have not found a proper solution. I have writen a desktop application for the hadoop job and I call it from web application.

Comment: Wow, that sounds scary... :-( OK, I try to experiment with it the next days, maybe I find a solution...

Comment: if you find a solution, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the basic Hadoop HDFS stuff in version 2.7.1 working within WildFly 9.0.1. Details can be found in my Blog: http://rick-rainer-ludwig.com/2015/09/01/hadoop-client-in-wildfly-a-difficult-marriage

The basic steps are:

- Switch off implicit bean archive support and force all JAR files to contain a META-INF/beans.xml if CDI beans are included. Some Hadoop client dependencies contain @Inject, which make WildFly fail during deployment
- Add additional dependencies for jersey-server and jersey-json to bring the project into a state where it can compile. The Hadoop client dependency is not self contained. So, the additional dependencies are needed to add some missing classes.
- Exclude hadoop-mapreduce-client-app and hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient, because they try to provide a service which cannot start due to missing dependencies in WildFly. Not idea, what they are for and why they are packaged there.
- If you rely on Jackson 2, you need to package the whole Hadoop client into an own EAR, because Hadoop client enforces Jackson 1 via an packaged Provider. The EAR needs to provide a proxy with a well defined interface like a REST service or an EJB with remote interface.

Comment: thank you for reply. I can not go back from this point now but I hope this helps other people.

Comment: You are welcome. At the end it is not that different to your solution. You need to isolate the Hadoop client from the JavaEE part. You did it with an JavaSE application, I do it with another EAR. Hopefully, they get this packaging cleaned up in future.